# PIC16 microcontroller_ no output even after following tutorial

Tags: c, pic, mplab-x-5.50

I am using PICKIT 4, [PIC16F18446](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Microchip-8-bit-PIC-MCU-PIC16(L)F18426_46-Datasheet-40001985A.pdf) microcontroller, and MPLAB X IDE. I am following an instruction provided from Microchip, [Measuring frequency](https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/pr/GUID-545F8DE4-E169-4427-8F08-0AF83745FC3E-en-US-4/index.html?GUID-85A38DAB-B5FB-4EA1-BE35-D7833833ECE7)

Update:

I am not entirely sure what i needs to change but I am consistently getting an output of Frequency: 25536 whether there is an input signal or not. (Image of the output, and pin configuration shown below)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is `main()` your entire code? All you do is enable global interrupts and peripheral interrupts and then go into an infinite loop. In order for something to happen, you have to define an interrupt handler for a specific interrupt (pin, etc..) and then for example the interrupt will fire when that pin value goes high or low (however you define the response). Just enabling the global and peripheral interrupts enables the checking and response to interrupts but doesn't set up any one specific interrupt. Those are just preliminary steps.

Comment: What means. "not getting anything out"?

Comment: You can't get anything out OF WHAT? AFAIS you don't configure any pin as output so you don't expect an output from chip. The only thing left is the MPLABX IDE output. Do you mean when you generate MCC code you don't see any output? Please kindly clarify your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Original Poster is using a PIC18 tutorial for a PIC16F target.

The MPLABX Code Configurator (MCC) tool is an awful thing for anyone new to the Microchip development tools to use.

An MPLABX project that does what I think this tutorial is about for the PIC16F18446 target is [here](https://github.com/dsoze1138/16F18446_TIMER1) in my git hub repository.

MCC was used to create most of this code so you should be able to see how it was done.

This code runs in the MPLABX simulator but that is a buggy hot mess. Use it with caution.

Comment: I am kind of happy that there is something like MCC. Seeing code generate and learning from it is really helpful. I intentionally used PIC16 instead of PIC18, and I made sure to choose RB4 of PIC16 as its has a timer (TIG).  I am trying to measure frequency. Your code seems similar to the code generate by MCC which helps a lot in understanding.

Comment: @SamShurp 
I have updated my repository to do exactly what the PIC18F tutorial talks about with regard to using the TIMER1 gate input to measure the cycle time of the input then report that frequency in Hz.

Comment: I have been trying to understand what's going by looking at your code, and MCC generated code. I have updated the post. I appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out; it finally works.